# Layer Join and Styling Trouble because of Field Types

Tags: qgis, shapefile, style, csv, attribute-joins

I am trying to join a `.csv`-file with als rates and zip3 values to a shapefile with zip3 values and then color the map based on the als rates.

This seems very simple and I have done similar maps before but I am having trouble with the field types. Whenever I import the CSV it makes all of the field types strings and I am not able to change them even using the refactoring toolbox. Then when I join them they are still strings and I am not able to style them using graduated symbols because they are not numerical.

Here is a link to the shapefiles and the csv that I am using: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X26BXzrCtjSGuAPweH3HPiGshcfGaU6U?usp=sharing

I am using QGIS version 3.10

Comment: You could run `refactor fields` on the joined layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **layer style panel**, use an expression to convert your string type into real.

Insted of using `rates`, use `to_real("rates")` and it will work (supposing your field is named "rates").

[image: works with to_real expression]

[image: map example]

Answer (score 1):

I think [@romainbh already gave a better answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/376615/107424), but you can also force QGIS to interpret CSV colums as a special datatype by using a CSV-T.

Therefore create a new textfile, fill it with the column-datatypes of your CSV like this:

```
"Integer(10)","Real(10.5)","String(80)"
```

You can use `Integer`, `Real`, `String`, `Date`, `Time` and `DateTime`. Do not add any more content to it. Then save it having the same filename as your actual CSV into the same folder, just having the ending `.csvt`. If you now load it, your CSV should have the correct datatypes.